# Dplyr and RStudio code completion for column name

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

dplyr is a great package, however code completion is very convenient and time saving.
Is there a solution where RStudio's code completion (for column names) could be used in select, filter and other dplyr functions if the dataset is passed in the first pipeline position?

In the example below, if mtcars has 80+ columns with long names, it would be nice to press `c` and ctrl+space to get all columns starting with `c`. Is there a workaround to achieve that?

```
mtcars %>% select(cyl)
```

Something like

[image]

Comment: Just don't use pipes, `dplyr` works without it too. The following will work `select(mtcars$[press TAB])`. And you don't need to press ctrl+space, just press TAB

Comment: @DavidArenburg, as far as I understand, `dplyr` was meant to be used with pipes because it allows a more natural writing and reading of code, from left to right instead of inside out, so I don't agree with your general remark of "Just don't use pipes" when using dplyr.

Comment: This is something that's in the pipeline for RStudio's TAB completion -- it's not there yet, but it will be.

Comment: @KevinUshey, nice to know, looking forward to that!